# When does Kafka Stream Processor commit? Can we be fault-tolerant without logging?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Let's say I have as simple processor that outputs the latest record for each key, using an internal version that is not necessarily the same as the Kafka timestamp (so compacted log is not possible).

```
public class LatestProcessor implements Processor<Long, Dto> {
    private ProcessorContext context = null;
    private KeyValueStore<Long, Dto> kvStore;

    public LatestProcessor () {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.kvStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore(Config.stateStore);
        this.context.schedule(Duration.ofMillis(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)),
                PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, (l) -> {
                    this.punctuate(l);
                });
    }


    @Override
    public void process(Long key, Dto message) {
        Dto current = kvStore.get(key);
        if (current == null || current.version() <= message.version()) {
              kvStore.put(key, message);
        }
    }


    public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
        // processes all the messages in the state
        KeyValueIterator<Long, Dto> iter = this.kvStore.all();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            KeyValue<Long, Dto> entry = iter.next();
            context.forward(entry.key, entry.value);
            kvStore.delete(entry.key);

          
        }
        iter.close();
        context.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        kvStore.close();
    }

}
```

Is it possible for this processor to be fault-tolerant with a state store without logging? This would require that we only commit records that have been processed by punctuate. If the stream commits records that have not been through punctuate, then I would assume we would need to add logging to the state store.

We can assume the Topology is only this processor, and it forwards to a downstream topic.

The code above works, but its unclear how we can test given that the commit() is not guaranteed to commit.